# What is a good method to split workload fairly between threads if they're working on a single matrix?

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, pthreads

Say you have a [10x10] matrix of 1s and 0s as such:

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

and you launch 'x' instances of a worker thread to manipulate the same matrix, what is a good method of making sure the workload is fairly divided between each thread so each worker thread gets a more-or-less equal amount of space to work on.

Initially I thought it would be a good idea to split it by columns so that if we were to launch 3 instances it would look something like this :

```
wT[1]      wT[2]      wT[3]
0 1 0   |  0 0 1   |  1 1 0 1 
1 0 0   |  1 0 1   |  0 1 0 1 
1 1 1   |  0 0 0   |  0 0 1 1 
1 0 1   |  1 0 1   |  0 1 1 0 
1 1 0   |  0 0 0   |  0 0 0 0 
1 1 0   |  1 1 1   |  1 1 1 0 
1 0 0   |  1 1 0   |  1 0 1 0 
0 1 0   |  0 0 0   |  1 0 0 0 
1 0 0   |  0 1 1   |  1 0 0 1
```

Some of my classmates suggested using modulo so that each row is given to a thread until no more rows remain.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Your example is several orders of magnitude too small to benefit from multithreading.

Comment: Easiest would be splitting it evenly initially, but the most effective would be splitting initially and determining whether to add more or less to each thread.

Comment: @EOF that's just an example to keep it simple. In reality I'm trying to code Conway's Game of Life on  a 800x600 board. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user100000 Thread synchronization overhead will likely negate all benefit from threading for such a small board. I'd recommend SIMD instead.

Comment: @Jerry so if I understood correctly: split evenly; if remainder, add one by one to each thread, until no more remainder?

Comment: @user100000 Yep. Split evenly, when one thread finishes have it notify the thread with the biggest workload, then that thread splits its workload with the finished thread. But like EOF said, this is quite a small workload there will probably be nearly no benefit from multithreading.

Comment: It is better if the memory assigned to each thread is (at least somewhat) contiguous. This suggests that a row-based division is better than a column based. This is especially true when the matrix is too large to fit in the faster caches.